# Changing order of summation for simple integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I want to change the summation or the following integral:

$ \intop_{0}^{2\pi}dx\intop_{0}^{\sin x}f\left(x,y\right)dy $.

Now I know that $ x=\left(-1\right)^{k}\arcsin\left(y\right)+\pi k $ and if we want to write $ sinx $ as combination of funcions of $ y $ it should be as described in the attached picture (first the green part, then the purple and the blue).

But I'm not sure that I understand why exactly it is correct. Can anyone provide a simple explanation? thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that you need to split the integral in only two parts, one in the region with $x$ from $0$ to $\pi$, and one with $x$ from $\pi$ to $2\pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing here is that $$-\frac{\pi}{2} \le \arcsin y \le \frac{\pi}{2} $$

When $x\in [0, \frac{\pi}{2} ] $, $x$ is just $\arcsin y$.

When $x\in[\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2} ] $, we have to manipulate the expression so as to match up the ranges, while still making sure that taking the sine of it gives $y$. This is only achieved by the expression $$\frac{\pi}{2} \le\pi - \arcsin y  \le \frac{3\pi}{2}$$

Similarly, when $x\in [\frac{3\pi}{2} , \frac{5\pi}{2} ] $ we have to add $2\pi$. This makes sure that the value of its sine is conserved, and that the ranges of the new expression and $x$ are the same: $$\frac{3\pi}{2} \le \arcsin y +2\pi \le \frac{5\pi}{2} $$